# Stacked Card Animation not chahing the bg color of the first element

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have created an animation in which several cards are stacked one behind the other. The aim is that the card in front disappears after a certain time, reappears at the back and the cards behind it come to the front, etc. The problem is that the animation has problems in two places.

First, only the background colour of the first card (yellow) is shown, never the one behind it. Also, it looks like the card in front goes through all the cards. How can I fix these two problems?  Here is my current code.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    let sliderImagesBox = document.querySelectorAll('.cards-box');
    sliderImagesBox.forEach(el => {
        let imageNodes = el.querySelectorAll('.card:not(.hide)');
        let arrIndexes = [];
        (() => {
            let start = 0;
            while (imageNodes.length > start) {
                arrIndexes.push(start++);
            }
        })();

        let setIndex = (arr) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < imageNodes.length; i++) {
                imageNodes[i].dataset.slide = arr[i];
                if (arr[i] === 0) {
                    imageNodes[i].classList.add('fade-out');
                    imageNodes[i].classList.remove('fade-in');
                    imageNodes[i].classList.add('color-' + arr[(i + 1) % imageNodes.length]); // Farbe ändern
                } else {
                    imageNodes[i].classList.remove('fade-out', 'fade-in');
                    imageNodes[i].classList.remove('color-' + arr[i]); // Farbe entfernen
                }
            }
        }

        let rotateCards = () => {
            arrIndexes.unshift(arrIndexes.pop());
            setIndex(arrIndexes);
        }

        el.addEventListener('click', rotateCards);
        setIndex(arrIndexes);

        setInterval(rotateCards, 2000);
    });
};
```

```css
body {
  background: #D6D3CE;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.cards-box {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-15px);
}

.cards-box .card {
  width: calc(18rem + 19vh);
  max-width: 80vw;
  background: #f7fffd;
  border-radius: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.98, 0.45, 1);
}

.cards-box .card.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* verhindert Klick auf das ausblendende Element */
}

.cards-box .card:not(.hide) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.98, 0.45, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.cards-box .card:not(.hide)[data-slide="0"] {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1);
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #F6FF94;
}

.cards-box .card:not(.hide)[data-slide="1"] {
  transform: translate(30px, -35px) scale(0.975);
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.cards-box .card:not(.hide)[data-slide="2"] {
  transform: translate(60px, -65px) scale(0.95);
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: #B5B2A9;
}

.cards-box .card:not(.hide)[data-slide="3"] {
  transform: translate(90px, -95px) scale(0.925);
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.cards-box .card:not(.hide)[data-slide="4"] {
  transform: translate(120px, -120px) scale(0.9);
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #F6FF94;
}

.cards-box .card:not(.hide)[data-slide="5"] {
  transform: translate(85px, -85px) scale(0.875);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.cards-box .card:not(.hide)[data-slide="0"] {
  transition: all 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.98, 0.45, 1);
}

.content-placeholder {
  padding: 14px 18px 20px;
}

.content-placeholder .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: calc(.8rem + 0.4vw);
}

.content-placeholder .row .img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #000;
  width: calc(56px + 2vw);
  height: calc(56px + 2vw);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.content-placeholder .row .img::after {
  content: attr(data-letter);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: calc(30px + 1vw);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.content-placeholder .row .img-text {
  background: #000;
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 145px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content-placeholder .row .img-text::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content-placeholder .text {
  background: #000;
  width: 90%;
  height: 2vh;
  min-height: 12px;
  max-height: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content-placeholder .text.text--m {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  height: 2vh;
  min-height: 12px;
}

.content-placeholder .text.text--s {
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  height: 2vh;
  min-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-box">
    <div class="card hide">
      <div class="content-placeholder">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="img"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="text text--l"></div>
        <div class="text text--m"></div>
        <div class="text text--s"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="content-placeholder">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="img" data-letter="T"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="text text--l"></div>
        <div class="text text--m"></div>
        <div class="text text--s"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="content-placeholder">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="img" data-letter="M"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="text text--l"></div>
        <div class="text text--m"></div>
        <div class="text text--s"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="content-placeholder">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="img" data-letter="K"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="text text--l"></div>
        <div class="text text--m"></div>
        <div class="text text--s"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="content-placeholder">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="img" data-letter="G"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="text text--l"></div>
        <div class="text text--m"></div>
        <div class="text text--s"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="content-placeholder">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="img" data-letter="G"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="text text--l"></div>
        <div class="text text--m"></div>
        <div class="text text--s"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the answer but it can be an idea, why don't you first disappear your card then remove it and after that just add it again to your stack,

like for disappearing when your card is displaying set their `max-width:100vh`(or any height you want to have at its maximum) `opacity:1` `overflow:auto` `transition:all .8s`(you set the `transition` for when you want to display it again after its disappearance, and `all` and `time` value is arbitrary) and set `max-width:0` `opacity:0` `overflow:none` `tarnsition:all .8s`,

in this case when you want to disappear the card by an action like click or scroll it just fades but it is there because we set its dimensions to 0 so now after its disappearance you should remove it to avoid any future problems and this can be done  with `removeChild()` (it's better to use `removeChild()` with `setTimeOut()` and set the time for the `setTimeoutOut` like a little bit longer than(like .1s ) your `transition` time because while the disappearance process is over your element would be removed )

after that you removed your element you can create it again with `createElement` and add it to your stack(I think the process of adding card to stack is getting done by that arrays)

I hope it can help you... I think with this method your card doesn't get through other cards...